# How to parse an RSS feed with XmlPullParser?

Tags: android, rss, xmlpullparser

I would like to parse a RSS feed. My question is how I can parse all tags between the `<item>`and `</item>` tags.

Given this very simple XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<rss version="2.0">
<channel>
  <title>MyRSSPage</title>
  <link>http://www.example.com</link>
  <item>
  <link>www.example.com/example1</link>
  <title>Example title 1</title>
  </item>
  <item>
  <link>www.example.com/example2</link>
  <title>Example title 2</title>
  </item>
</channel>
</rss>
```

I would like to parse just the stuff between the `<item>...</item>` tags.

```
            List<RssMessage> messages = new ArrayList<RssMessage>();

            // parser is a XmlPullParser instance
            while(parser.next() != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
                if (parser.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
                    continue;
                }
            String name = parser.getName();
            // START OF HEADER
            if(name.equals("title")) {
                title = parser.nextText();
            }
            else if(name.equals("link")) {
                link = parser.nextText();
            }
            else if(name.equals("description")) {
                description = parser.nextText();
            }
            else if(name.equals("language")) {
                language = parser.nextText();
            }
            else if(name.equals("copyright")) {
                copyright = parser.nextText();
            }
            else if(name.equals("pubDate")) {
                pubdate = parser.nextText();
            }
            // END OF HEADER

            else if(name.equals("item")) {
                RssMessage rssMessage = processItem(parser);
                messages.add(rssMessage);
            }
        }
```

In the below method I would like to just parse the tags within the `<item>...</item>`tags. How do I construct a loop that just goes through the item between `<item>` and `</item>`?

**EDIT** 

This is almost working. But sometimes not all elements are initiated even if the corresponding element in the RSS xml DO exist! Is something wrong with the below code?

```
private RssMessage processItem(XmlPullParser parser) throws IOException, XmlPullParserException {
        RssMessage rssMessage = new RssMessage();
    parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, ns, "item");
    while (parser.next() != XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
        if (parser.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
            continue;
        }
        String name = parser.getName();
        if(name.equals("link")) {
            rssMessage.setLink(parser.nextText());
        }
        else if(name.equals("guid")) {
            rssMessage.setGuid(parser.nextText());
        }
        else if(name.equals("category")) {
            rssMessage.setCategory(parser.nextText());
        }
        else if(name.equals("title")) {
            rssMessage.setTitle(parser.nextText());
        }
        else if(name.equals("pubDate")) {
            rssMessage.setPubDate(parser.nextText());
        }
    }
    return rssMessage;
    }
```

Comment: what's wrong with the code? any problem.

Comment: Nothing is wrong except that I don´t know how to parse the tags just between `<item>`and `</item>`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try the below.

```
try {
    XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
    factory.setNamespaceAware(false);
    XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();
    xpp.setInput(url.openConnection().getInputStream(), "UTF_8"); 
    //xpp.setInput(getInputStream(url), "UTF-8");

    boolean insideItem = false;

    // Returns the type of current event: START_TAG, END_TAG, etc..
    int eventType = xpp.getEventType();
    while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
        if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {

            if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("item")) {
                insideItem = true;
            } 
            else if(xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("title")) 
            {

            }
        }
        eventType = xpp.next(); //move to next element
    }

} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Edit:

```
XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
factory.setNamespaceAware(false);
XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();
xpp.setInput(open,null);
// xpp.setInput(getInputStream(url), "UTF-8");

boolean insideItem = false;

// Returns the type of current event: START_TAG, END_TAG, etc..
int eventType = xpp.getEventType();
while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
    if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {

        if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("item")) {
            insideItem = true;
        } else if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("title")) {
            if (insideItem)
                Log.i("....",xpp.nextText()); // extract the headline
        } else if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("link")) {
            if (insideItem)
                Log.i("....",xpp.nextText());  // extract the link of article
        }
    } else if (eventType == XmlPullParser.END_TAG && xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("item")) {
        insideItem = false;
    }

    eventType = xpp.next(); // move to next element
}
```

Output

```
www.example.com/example1
Example title 1
www.example.com/example2
Example title 2
```

Comment: Have a look at my edit in my post above. My question is rather about how I may parse the elements between the `<item>` and `</item>` tags.

Comment: try the edit. it should work. http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.html

Comment: @Raghunandan can you send me any lin for between the `<item>` and `</item>` tags example

Comment: @Raghunandan can you explain little bit more example for this

Comment: @NagarjunaReddy where do you need explanation. Also you can copy the xml to assests fodler and use the same that op has in the question

Comment: @Raghunandan once see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24734312/parse-an-rss-feed-in-android

Comment: @NagarjunaReddy and the problem is??

Comment: @NagarjunaReddy answered your post. Rest is upto you. Good luck. I could not reply fast.

Comment: For something like a LINK that comes w/out a closing tag and is in the HREF attribute, here's how to get it: `String linkUrl = xpp.getAttributeValue(null, HREF);`