# I'm having trouble with XML parser in android

Tags: android, rss, feed, android-xmlpullparser

I keep seeing tutorials but it doesn't help, I'm using the XmlPullParser but it keeps getting an error and the application shows xmlerror page, is it because of the format of the xml?

here is what I'm doing:

```
public class XmlParser {
    private static final String ns = null;


    public Queue<Item> parse(InputStream in) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {

        try {
            XmlPullParser parser = Xml.newPullParser();
            parser.setFeature(XmlPullParser.FEATURE_PROCESS_NAMESPACES, false);
            parser.setInput(in, null);
            parser.nextTag();
            return readFeed(parser);

        } finally {
            in.close();
        }
    }

    private Queue<Item> readFeed(XmlPullParser parser) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
        Queue<Item> resp = new LinkedList<Item>();


        parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, ns, "channel");
        while (parser.next() != XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
            if (parser.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
                continue;
            }
            String name = parser.getName();

            if (name.equals("item")) {
                resp.add(readItem(parser));
            } else {
                skip(parser);
            }
        }
        return resp;
    }

    // This class represents a single entry (post) in the XML feed.
    // It includes the data members "title," "link," and "summary."
    public static class Item {
        public final String title;
        public final String link;
        public final String summary;

        private Item(String title, String summary, String link) {
            this.title = title;
            this.summary = summary;
            this.link = link;
        }


    }

    // Parses the contents of an entry. If it encounters a title, summary, or link tag, hands them
    // off
    // to their respective &quot;read&quot; methods for processing. Otherwise, skips the tag.
    private Item readItem(XmlPullParser parser) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
        parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, ns, "item");
        String title = null;
        String summary = null;
        String link = null;
        System.out.print("entrou readItem");
        while (parser.next() != XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
            if (parser.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
                continue;
            }
            String name = parser.getName();
            if (name.equals("title")) {
                title = readTitle(parser);
            } else if (name.equals("description")) {
                summary = readDescription(parser);
            } else if (name.equals("link")) {
                link = readLink(parser);
            } else {
                skip(parser);
            }
        }
        return new Item(title, summary, link);
    }

    // Processes title tags in the feed.
    private String readTitle(XmlPullParser parser) throws IOException, XmlPullParserException {
        System.out.print("entrou title");
        parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, ns, "title");
        String title = readText(parser);
        parser.require(XmlPullParser.END_TAG, ns, "title");
        return title;
    }

    // Processes link tags in the feed.
    private String readLink(XmlPullParser parser) throws IOException, XmlPullParserException {
        parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, ns, "link");

        String link = readText(parser);
        parser.require(XmlPullParser.END_TAG, ns, "link");
        return link;
    }

    // Processes summary tags in the feed.
    private String readDescription(XmlPullParser parser) throws IOException, XmlPullParserException {
        parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, ns, "description");
        String summary = readText(parser);
        parser.require(XmlPullParser.END_TAG, ns, "description");
        return summary;
    }

    // For the tags title and summary, extracts their text values.
    private String readText(XmlPullParser parser) throws IOException, XmlPullParserException {
        String result = "";
        if (parser.next() == XmlPullParser.TEXT) {
            result = parser.getText();
            parser.nextTag();
        }
        return result;
    }

    // Skips tags the parser isn't interested in. Uses depth to handle nested tags. i.e.,
    // if the next tag after a START_TAG isn't a matching END_TAG, it keeps going until it
    // finds the matching END_TAG (as indicated by the value of "depth" being 0).
    private void skip(XmlPullParser parser) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
        if (parser.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
            throw new IllegalStateException();
        }
        int depth = 1;
        while (depth != 0) {
            switch (parser.next()) {
            case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
                    depth--;
                    break;
            case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                    depth++;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and here is the feed I'm trying to pull info from:

http://feeds.folha.uol.com.br/poder/rss091.xml

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to parse an RSS feed with XmlPullParser?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17434135/how-to-parse-an-rss-feed-with-xmlpullparser)

Answer (score 0):

Solved, I think if you are using XMLParser you have to make sure you are accessing an 1.0 or higher, when I used a Xml 2.0 it worked like a charm. Anybody can confirm this?